# Should I save validation $_POST value into a variable or not in CI?

Tags: codeigniter

E.g. I have something like this in my controller:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|xss_clean');
```

Now my question is, if I later in my code do something like this (inside the same method):

```
$user_profiles = array(

'email' => $_POST['email'],
'name' => $_POST['name']
);
```

Will, the variables in this array sanitized or not?

I mean will the form_validation->set_rules remain for all the later code usage of the $_POST values or I need to use some other technique?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Codeigniter provides the input class which has a method post that can get the values you require, after they have been sanitised by the form validation:

```
$user_profiles = array(
    'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
    'name' => $this->input->post('name')
);
```

I would more or less recommend that you use $this->input->post() instead of $_POST unless there is a specific reason not to. The docs have some more explanation and uses of the input class: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/libraries/input.html.

Comment: So, are you saying that when using post('email') instaed of $_POST['email'] it will remember the previous sanitation?

Comment: If you do call $this->input->post('email') after you've called $this->form_validation->run() then yes, the value returned will have been processed by whatever you put in the rules, eg. 'trim|xss_clean'

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure but as far as i know, form_validation just tests variables for given arguments, but dosen't clean them up.

I have always used `$postdata = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);` when handling form data.